# debugging rust on Eclipse Corrosion no longer works on fresh install

Tags: eclipse, debugging, rust

I change my Hard drive and so I made a fresh Eclipse Corrosion install but I kept my Rust projets. Problem is I get an error when I launch my prog in debug mode. It seems to work in run mode but I didn't test this that much.

Error is
An internal error occurred during: "Launching my_prog".
Cannot read the array length because "launchConfigEnv" is null

Important note : it seems to be link with the use of an input file (debug configuration/common/input file)

I try many things, many installs, new projects, many, many things but nothing works (and I cannot figure out what launchConfigEnv is).

Any help welcome...

Edit : I install 2019.12 Eclipse and it works fine. I will work a little with this version and try out more configuration to shrink the problem.

Comment: Same issue on Eclipse 2021-09-M3A.
`Corrosion: Rust edition in Eclipse IDE 1.2.1.202106081156 org.eclipse.corrosion.feature.feature.group Eclipse Corrosion`
`Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers 4.21.0.20210827-1400 epp.package.embedcpp Eclipse Packaging Project`

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, add a single environment variable to the launch configuration, as follows:

[image: Launch configuration]

Once that is done, re-launch it and it should work.

Note that in order to get rust debugging working in Eclipse I installed MSYS2 and the following MSYS2 packages.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
pacman -S man
```

I followed some instructions in the Rust Corrosion Trouble Shooting guide to get a working GDB.

Reference: https://github.com/eclipse/corrosion/blob/master/documentation/Troubleshooting.md#debugging-on-windows

The Rust debugger command needs to be changed to rust-dbg.cmd, as follows:

[image: rust-gdb.cmd configuration]

However, the PATH environment wasn't working for me, so in the rust-gdb.cmd script I added this near the top:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;F:\msys64\mingw64\bin;F:\Data\.cargo\bin
```

(Adjust as-per your installation of MSYS2 and Cargo/Rustup)

After which Eclipse was able to start a debug session and stop at a breakpoint.

[image: Eclipse rust debugging session]

Comment: I raised a bug report for this issue here:

https://github.com/eclipse/corrosion/issues/379